# How can I parse a data to json and call only the value

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-4

I have a code output that looks like this,

```
$x = FileDBConsistency::join('Servers', 'Servers.srv_id', '=', 'FileDBConsistency.srv_id')
  ->where( 'Servers.srv_ip', $ip )
  ->get( array('FileDBConsistency.fileconflict_filename') );

$data = explode(',', $x);

return Response::json( $data  );
```

It would display like this

```
[

    "[{\"fileconflict_filename\":\"belove giles whatever",
    " filename1",
    " uxomv4e7jj3g",
    " zd9afzfm3eb2\"}]"

]
```

is there a way to display it in json and display it like this

P.S i only need to access the values without the key

```
[

     "belove giles whatever",
     "filename1",
     "uxomv4e7jj3g",
     "zd9afzfm3eb2"

]
```

If i remove the `$data = explode()` and change the return to return `Response::json( $x);`

this is the result

```
[

    {
        "fileconflict_filename": "belove giles whatever, filename1, uxomv4e7jj3g, zd9afzfm3eb2"
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to decode json string yourself by using `explode()`. Try `json_decode()` instead of exploding it before outputting?

I'm not sure how your `$x` result is structured, but something along this line:

```
$x = FileDBConsistency::join('Servers', 'Servers.srv_id', '=', 'FileDBConsistency.srv_id')
    ->where( 'Servers.srv_ip', $ip )
    ->get( array('FileDBConsistency.fileconflict_filename') );

$data = json_decode($x);

return Response::json($data);
```

---

From your additional explanation, you'll need to pluck the value out before exploding them, like this:

```
$x = FileDBConsistency::join('Servers', 'Servers.srv_id', '=', 'FileDBConsistency.srv_id')
    ->where( 'Servers.srv_ip', $ip )
    ->pluck('FileDBConsistency.fileconflict_filename');

$data = explode($x);

return Response::json($data);
```

Comment: @AkoSi Asiong I've updated my answer with your additional info